# Why is atom having weird colors in the side bar and how do i get them back to default

Tags: themes, customization, atom-editor

[Atom-Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03tf0.png)

this is what my editor looks rn i dont remember what made it this way is there anything i can do to make it as default?

Answer (score 0):

Open settings and click on Themes. Set the UI theme and Syntax Theme to Atom Light. This will bring you back to the UI you saw when you first launched the application.